# DataTable - Header table and body table not aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Basically, I am using two data tables in my view.
First table contains headers, sub headers and aggregated data.
Second one contains actual dataset.

jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dhruvsha2707/w85x9bmL/

Both tables have same numbers of columns and shares same properties (eg. width, height, colspan, rowspans etc) but even then, both have asymmetric column width.
Is there any solution for this?

This is how columns looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8MC5.png

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  fnLoadDataTableInstance();
})

function fnLoadDataTableInstance() {
  var headerSource = [{
    aggregation: '-',
    pnl_l: '70.1',
    pnl_s: '-8.5',
    pnl_t: '61.6',
    exp_l: '10.89',
    exp_s: '-2.0',
    exp_n: '-5.51',
    exp_g: '20.18',
    p: '104',
    l: '90',
    s: '11'
  }];
  var dataSource = [{
      aggregation: 'Sector A',
      pnl_l: '0.0',
      pnl_s: -'11.9',
      pnl_t: '-11.9',
      exp_l: '0.0',
      exp_s: '-7.57',
      exp_n: '-7.55',
      exp_g: '7.55',
      p: '3',
      l: '0',
      s: '3'
    },
    {
      aggregation: 'Sector B',
      pnl_l: '51.7',
      pnl_s: -'3.9',
      pnl_t: '47.8',
      exp_l: '4.72',
      exp_s: '-0.37',
      exp_n: '-4.35',
      exp_g: '5.08',
      p: '22',
      l: '20',
      s: '2'
    },
    {
      aggregation: 'Sector C',
      pnl_l: '18.4',
      pnl_s: '7.3',
      pnl_t: '25.7',
      exp_l: '6.17',
      exp_s: '5.94',
      exp_n: '6.39',
      exp_g: '7.55',
      p: '79',
      l: '70',
      s: '6'
    }
  ];

  $('#dtExampleHeader').DataTable({
    dom: 'F',
    data: headerSource,
    columns: [{
        data: 'aggregation'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_l'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_s'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_t'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_l'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_s'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_n'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_g'
      },
      {
        data: 'p'
      },
      {
        data: 'l'
      },
      {
        data: 's'
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No data available"
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {}
  });

  $('#dtExampleBody').DataTable({
    dom: 'F',
    data: dataSource,
    columns: [{
        data: 'aggregation'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_l'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_s'
      },
      {
        data: 'pnl_t'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_l'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_s'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_n'
      },
      {
        data: 'exp_g'
      },
      {
        data: 'p'
      },
      {
        data: 'l'
      },
      {
        data: 's'
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No data available"
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dataTableExample" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <div id="headerTable">
      <table width="100%" id="dtExampleHeader" class="display cell-border compact stripe" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" width="100">Aggregation</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="3">P&amp;L</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="4">Exposure(%) </th>
            <th rowspan="2">#P</th>
            <th rowspan="2">#L</th>
            <th rowspan="2">#S</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>L</th>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>T</th>
            <th>L</th>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyTable">
      <table width="100%" id="dtExampleBody" class="display cell-border compact stripe" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr style="height: 0px; display: none;">
            <th rowspan="2" width="100"></th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="3"></th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="4"></th>
            <th rowspan="2"></th>
            <th rowspan="2"></th>
            <th rowspan="2"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr style="height: 0px; display: none;">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Of course they are going to have different column widths; they are two separate tables...

Comment: A DataTable can have so-called [complex headers](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html).

Comment: Also the issue with misalignment was because of some css issues, and th count as well. updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/asjaindev/xefy7Lvc/2/